# jQuery live click fires more than once

Tags: jquery, click, live

I have this code for ajax a page on search click:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ClientsList.asp",
    type: "POST",
    data: "name=" + Name + "&org=" + Org + "&job=" + Job + "&type=" + Type,
    success: function(msg){
        $("#SRP").html(msg);
        $("#Loading").fadeOut("noraml",function(){
            $("#SRP").fadeIn();
        });

    }
});
```

then in the content loaded I have checkboxes that I need to catch, so I do that with this code

```
$(".SearchResultSelectBox").live("click", function(event) {
    $(this).is(":checked") ? DoCheckSelect($(this).attr("rel")) : unDoCheckSelect($(this).attr("rel"));
});
```

The first time I search and get the resulted page from the ajax the checkbox work great. the second time I use the search, every live click I have is doubled. the third time I use the ajax, every live click is tripled and so on...

I tried "return false" but then it work but the checkbox doesn't get clicked

What can be done?

**NEVER MIND! I had a mistake, I had the second set of function inside of the first one so every time I made the search function I made the inside function for live click again**

Comment: Are you calling `live()` more than once?  Try `event.stopPropagation();` in the `click()` routine if not.

Comment: Well you were calling it more than once then.  Easily done.

Comment: If you calling the `live()` function every time you load content, you are missing the point of the `live`. you should only register a live event once, and then whenever you refresh the html, it passes through it.

Comment: Or are you declaring it in a loop or an event handler itself that may fire more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be try to use

> unbind('click');

and bind it again for each ajax request

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
event.stopPropagation();

$(".SearchResultSelectBox").live("click", function(event) {
    $(this).is(":checked") ? DoCheckSelect($(this).attr("rel")) : unDoCheckSelect($(this).attr("rel"));
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```